# File-upload fails when called via a service i.e restTemplate.postForEntity

Tags: spring-boot, file-upload

I have below springboot rest end point to upload files.

```java
    @RequestMapping(
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                value = "/v1/file-upload",
                consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Response>  uploadFile (
                @RequestParam(value = "multipartFile") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
            String str = storeFile(multipartFile);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new Response("successfully uploaded with name "+str), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

and properties as below

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=30MB
```

this API when called via postman, working fine.

but when called via restTemplate from a service, it's throwing

```
{"timestamp":"2020-05-26T09:17:46.369+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field multipartFile exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes.","path":"/43c0800d-b992-45b6-8d25-9e81115539d0/Form/files/mock/api/v1/file-upload"}
```

exception.

my service calls as below

```java
    apiCallResponseObj = restClientUtil.postEntity(serviceUrl, Object.class, apiEndPoint.getFormData(), headers);
```

`apiEndPoint.getFormData()` has the multipart file data.

my question is, why am I getting an exception when called via a service?

using springboot 2.1.13

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with api-gateway (kong) where the limitations were put.
the configurations given in the question works fine.